# Get an element object of an array from a key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I'm parsing a csv fils to json with `node-csvtojson` and I got a JSONarray with the following code

```
csv({delimiter: ';'}).fromFile(path).then((jsonObj)=>{
    data = jsonObj;
    console.log(jsonObj);
})
```

with a csv like

```
a,b,c
A,B,C
1,2,3
1,B,C
```

I have got

```
[
{
 a: A,
 b: B,
 c: C,
},
{
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3,
},
{
 a: 1,
 b: B,
 c: C
}
]
```

But I want to find every object who has the element `a === 1` and I want to have all the content of the object,

like this:

```
{
 a: 1,
 b: 2,
 c: 3,
},
{
 a: 1,
 b: B,
 c: C,
}
```

But I 'm struggling to do that, I have tried with `array.filter` but without success then I have tried to do this with `array.map` but I got lost on how to do.

Do you have any idea on or I could do that ?

Than you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Array.filter` like so:

```js
const data = [{
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C',
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C'
  }
];

console.log(data.filter(({ a }) => a == 1));
```

If you want this to work with old browsers, here's an ES5-compliant version:

```js
var data = [{
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C',
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C'
  }
];

console.log(data.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.a == 1
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple use **[`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to filter through the object array and select the one having property `a === 1`

```js
var arr = [{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":1,"b":"B","c":"C"}];
const filteredArr = arr.filter(obj => obj.a === 1);
console.log(filteredArr);
```

Using **[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** you can do the same thing:

```js
var arr = [{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":1,"b":"B","c":"C"}];
const redArr = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
   return acc = obj.a === 1 ? acc.concat(obj) : acc;
}, []);
console.log(redArr);
```

Using **[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** for this problem is not the right approach, although it is possible:

```js
var arr = [{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":1,"b":"B","c":"C"}];
const mapArr = arr.map(obj => obj.a === 1 ? obj : undefined).filter(obj => obj); //hack to remove undefined elements
console.log(mapArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log([{
    a: 'A',
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C',
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 'B',
    c: 'C'
  }
].filter(o => o.a === 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
var arr = [{"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C"},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":1,"b":"B","c":"C"}];

var res = arr.filter(obj => obj.a === 1);

console.log(res);
```